# Parallelly resizing mutiple photos

Tags: c#, file, image, async-await

This code snippet is supposed to utilize async await to resize a photo file into multiple sizes in parallel. I just want to know if I am doing it in the right way. I would love to hear some ideas on how to report resize progress on file like how many of them completed.

```
public class PhotoProcessor : IPhotoProcessor
{
    public void Resize(string filePath, string dropLocation, List<Size> sizes)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(sizes, async (size) =>
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            var result = await Resize(filePath, dropLocation, size);
            Console.WriteLine($"Done {result} Resizing {fileName} to {size}");
        });
    }

    public async Task<bool> Resize(string filePath, string dropLocation, Size size)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"File {filePath} not found");
        }

        using (var image = new MagickImage(filePath))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            var newFileName = $"{fileName}_{size}{extension}";
            var newFilePath = $"{dropLocation}{newFileName}";

            var magickSize = new MagickGeometry(size.W, size.H);
            magickSize.IgnoreAspectRatio = false;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                image.Resize(magickSize);
                image.Write(newFilePath);
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: _I would love to hear some ideas on how to report resize progress on file like how many of them completed._ That this part of your question seems to be is off-topic because it is not implemented yet.

Comment: @t3chb0t thank you for the edit. Yes that part is not implemented but any suggestions on that are most welcome.

Comment: You are reading the image multiple times.  It is one hard drive with one set of RW heads.  Parallel is not gong to make the HW faster.  I bet a simple single read and multiple Resize and Write would be faster.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>     public void Resize(string filePath, string dropLocation, List<Size> sizes)
> ```

Why `List<>`? Following the principle of coding to the interface rather than the implementation, this should probably be `IList<>` or even `IReadOnlyList<>`.

---

> ```
>         Parallel.ForEach(sizes, async (size) =>
>         {
>             var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
>             var result = await Resize(filePath, dropLocation, size);
>             Console.WriteLine($"Done {result} Resizing {fileName} to {size}");
>         });
> ```

Why `async/await` inside `Parallel.ForEach`? If each size is handled on a different thread, there's nothing to be gained by using `await`.

---

> ```
>             var newFilePath = $"{dropLocation}{newFileName}";
> ```

`Path.Combine` exists for a reason: using that rather than manual concatenation will give more robust code.

---

> ```
>             await Task.Run(() =>
>             {
>                 image.Resize(magickSize);
>                 image.Write(newFilePath);
>             });
> ```

Pretend for a moment that we're not using `Parallel.ForEach`. The benefit of `async/await` with something like image processing is that you can keep the CPU busy even when one of the coroutines is blocked on I/O. But half of the I/O has already happened (maybe more if you're always scaling down rather than up). If you want to make an async version, the image load should be async.